# Adjust Firestore ServerTimestamp

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add extra time to the FireStore timestamp using cloud functions. With Realtime databases all I did was just use `event.data.ref.child('expiry').set(timestamp+duration);`. When I try the same with firestore I get weird data like [object Object]21600000.

Here is how I tried it with Firestore.

```
const duration = 21600000;
batch.update(firestore.collection("place_check_in").doc(checkInId),{expiryTimestamp:admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()+duration});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `serverTimestamp()` like that.  It doesn't have a date or time value on the client.  It's a sentinel token that tell Firestore to substitute the server time for that field.  It can only be used alone as a field value for a write operation.  If you need to alter that value, you'll have to do it later, after the value is written, such as in a Cloud Functions trigger, or on the client.

If you're running this code in Cloud Functions, you could instead just read the date directly from the system, as it is already guaranteed to be correct.  (The purpose of serverTimestamp() is to compensate for client devices whose clocks may not be accurate.)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response, reading the date directly from the system gives me a time that's 2 hours behind from my timezone, how can I change it to my timezone. I am a newbie on node.js

Comment: Timezones don't affect timestamps.  Any point in time is the same point in time for all people on earth.  Timezone is simply a concept that lets people think about the time of day in a local sense.

Comment: I understand that timestamps are not affected by timezones, what I am trying to say is that I am thinking of reading the date directly from the cloud system like you suggested and then adding the extra hours to it and pushing it to my firestore document. However, when I read the system time, its off by 2 hours..

Comment: It's not off.  You're simply taking a view of the date that's not localized to your own timezone.  If you want to view the date in your own timezone, you'll have to use a date library to format it the way you want.

Comment: @DougStevenson, Can you please tell me if two documents in a collection can have exactly the same Server Timestamp? Considering multiple clients will be writing to the collection, is the write itself queued by Firestore so the timestamp can never collide?

Comment: @RamIyer If you have a new question, post it separately.

Comment: @DougStevenson, Done. Posted a new question. Can you please take a look? Thank you. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65404643/2959575